# ERROR in Delete symfony 2

Tags: symfony

i have an error in delete method here is the error

EntityManager#remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.

here is the code :

public function supprimerAction($id){

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$Livre=$em->getRepository('EspritBibBundle:Livre')->find($id);
$em->remove($Livre);
$em->flush();


return $this->render('EspritBibBundle:Livre:succes.html.twig',array('msg'=>'Suppression effectué avec succés'));
```

}

Comment: If there is no Livre object with the id that you specified then `$Livre` will be `null`, in which case you cannot remove it.

Comment: thanks it worked for some Livres but didnt work others in the form

Comment: Regardless, you're still trying to remove entities that do not exist or they would be found by find($id). Whatever is passing $id to supprimerAction is wrong.  You should add some debugging code or throw an exception / print out the value of $id when $Livre is null so that you can figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 5):

Try with `findOneById()` and as Richard say, throw an exception if $livre = null

```
public function supprimerAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $livre = $em->getRepository('EspritBibBundle:Livre')->findOneById($id);

    if (!$livre) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No livre found for id '.$id);
    } 

    $em->remove($livre);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('EspritBibBundle:Livre:succes.html.twig',array('msg'=>'Suppression effectué avec succés'));
}
```